# Accepting 2 integers as console input & verify that each is an integer > 0

Tags: java, validation, input, integer

Here is my code:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of ROWS and COLUMNS of the array : ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int numRows = sc.nextInt();
int numColumns = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayRowColumnInputVerify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int rows = accept_user_input("ROWS");
        int cols = accept_user_input("COLUMNS");
        System.out.println("The rows and columns you entered are : " +rows  + " rows & " + cols + " columns.");
        
    }

    public static int  accept_user_input(String dimension) {
        int input_dimension=0;
        boolean input_correct=false;
        while(!input_correct) {
            System.out.print("Please, enter the number of " + dimension + " of the array : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            input_dimension = sc.nextInt();
            if (input_dimension>0) {
                input_correct=true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("The number you entered " + input_dimension + " must be greater than 0. ");
            }
        }
        return input_dimension;
    }
    
}
```

I hope the above helps. If you need help understanding the code I will be happy to explain.

Comment: A requirement is that the Rows and Columns be captured with 1 prompt. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RobertLewis  I have posted another answer accepting both at the same time as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean b = (numRows > 0 && numColums > 0);
System.out.println("Each number is > 0" + b);
```

b will be false if one of the numbers is <= 0;
b will be true if both > 0

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the input to be simultaneous maybe try :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayRowColumnInputVerify2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] dimensions = accept_user_input("ROWS & COLUMNS");
        System.out.println("The rows and columns you entered are : " +dimensions[0]  + " rows & " + dimensions[1] + " columns.");
        
    }

    public static int[]  accept_user_input(String dimension) {
        int rows=0;
        int cols=0;

        boolean input_correct=false;
        while(!input_correct) {
            System.out.print("Please, enter the number of " + dimension + " of the array : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            rows = sc.nextInt();
            cols = sc.nextInt();
            if (rows>0 && cols>0) {
                input_correct=true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("The number you entered :  rows:" + rows + " & cols:"+ cols + " must be greater than 0. ");
            }
        }
        int[] input = {rows, cols};
        return input;
    }
    
}
```

Simplified further:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayRowColumnInputVerify2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows=0;
        int cols=0;

        boolean input_correct=false;
        while(!input_correct) {
        System.out.print("Please, enter the number of ROWS & COLUMNS of the array : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            rows = sc.nextInt();
            cols = sc.nextInt();
            if (rows>0 && cols>0) {
                input_correct=true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("The number you entered :  rows:" + rows + " & cols:"+ cols + " must be greater than 0. ");
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("The rows and columns you entered are : " +rows  + " rows & " + cols + " columns.");
        
    }


    
}
```